# Qt's Signals/Slots temporary one time connection

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

I have an issue, maybe you can help me.

There is a amqp client in a specific thread which is communicate with a rabbitmq server.

I need to lock (and check if it’s already locked) some resource before a client starts to use it.
LockResource is an essential precondition for various functions.

In first example, I disconnect the last lamba connected, but there is a strange behavior, do_stuff() is sometime called, sometime not...

In the second example, all rights but it’s kill multi-threading.

In the third, to avoid memory leak, I need to change AmqpClient to emit resourceLocked all the time with a « magic number » when there is an error and check it before call do_stuff()… This not nice at all…

Maybe there is something I do wrong or I misunderstood.
If you have a better way, I take it.

---

EDIT 16/09/2018

I misled you with imprecises explanations:
do_stuff() is not an unique method but various instructions otherwise I would have connected it directly.
It would have been better to write […] instead of do_stuff().
Also there is only an unique client by instance.

I can’t know by advance what the user will execute first.
He can locks resource to readResourceContent, deleteResource, writeResourceProperty, …, so all of that must to execute differents instructions.

The good thing is that thanks to yours answers I have an working solution using `bool QMetaObject::invokeMethod(QObject *context, Functor function, Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection, FunctorReturnType *ret = nullptr)`

General declarations

```
using Callback = std::function<void()>;
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Callback)

qRegisterMetaType<Callback>("Callback");
```

AmqpClient.cpp

```
void AmqpClient::lockResource(Identifier identifier, QObject *context, const Callback &func)
{
    if(lockedResources_.contains(identifier))
    {
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(context,
                                  func,
                                  Qt::QueuedConnection);
        return;
    }

    QString queueName(QString::number(identifier) + ".lock");
    QAmqpQueue *lockQueue = client_->createQueue(queueName);

    connect(lockQueue, qOverload<QAMQP::Error>(&QAmqpQueue::error), this, [this](QAMQP::Error error) {
        if(error == QAMQP::ResourceLockedError) {
            emit errorMessage("The expected resource is already locked by another user.");
            sender()->deleteLater();
        }
    });

    connect(lockQueue, &QAmqpQueue::declared, this, [=]() {
        QAmqpQueue *lockQueue = qobject_cast<QAmqpQueue*>(sender());
        lockQueue->consume(QAmqpQueue::coExclusive);
        lockedResources_[identifier] = lockQueue;

        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(context,
                                  func,
                                  Qt::QueuedConnection);
    });

    lockQueue->declare(QAmqpQueue::Exclusive | QAmqpQueue::AutoDelete);
}
```

Controller.cpp

```
void Controller::readResourceContent(int row) 
{    
    [...]
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(amqp_,
                              "lockResource",
                              Qt::AutoConnection,
                              Q_ARG(Identifier, identifier),
                              Q_ARG(QObject*, this),
                              Q_ARG(Callback, [&](){ [...] }));
    [...]
}
```

---

1

```
// called not inside connect(...) because it may not to emit the signal 
// (if resource is already locked)
disconnect(amqp_, &AmqpClient::resourceLocked, 0, 0);

connect(amqp_, &AmqpClient::resourceLocked, this, [&](){
  do_stuff();
});

emit lockResource(identifier, QPrivateSignal());
```

2

```
// This is working like a charm, but I'm losing ui reactivity
QEventLoop loop;
connect(amqp_, &AmqpClient::resourceLocked, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
emit lockResource(identifier, QPrivateSignal());
loop.exec();
do_stuff();
```

3

```
// Using an intermediate object
class CallbackObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    std::function<void()> callback;

public:
    CallbackObject(std::function<void()> callback) : QObject(), callback(callback) {}

public slots:
    void execute() { callback(); deleteLater(); }
};

// Working but memory leak if signal is not emitted 
// resource already locked for example
CallbackObject *helper = new CallbackObject([&](){
  do_stuff() ;
});
connect(amqp_, &AmqpClient::resourceLocked, helper, &CallbackObject::execute);
emit lockResource(identifier, QPrivateSignal());
```

Comment: Why not using queued connection type (for thread)? Maybe add mutex/futex for control and checking available of resource? Why lambdas?

Comment: @Deep: If I'm not mistaken then these connections are already queued connections since the 4-parameter variety of `QObject::connect` detects that the sender `amqp_` and the receiver `this` live in differen threads.

Comment: You should wrap your resource locking into an object like `std::unique_ptr` or `QMutexLocker` or even `QSharedDataPointer` or `std::shared_ptr`/`QShardPointer`, or maybe `QPointer`, if it supports being locked/used by multiple objects at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to set up the following sequence of events:

```
          Client                          AMQPClient
             |       lockResource(id)        |
             |------------------------------>|
             |                               |
             |                               |--\
             |                               |   | 
             |        resourceLocked         |   | try to acquire resource
             |<------------------------------|   |
          /--|                               |<-/
do_stuff |   |                               |
          \->|                               |
             |                               |
```

where the message `resourceLocked` is not sent when `AMQP` can't acquire the resource and thus `do_stuff` also isn't called in that case.

The issue with `do_stuff` not being called when using implementation 1 is race condition when you have more than one client waiting for their respective resource to be locked simultaneously. One sequence demonstrating the issue you described (plus additional problems with that approach as well as with your implementation 3) is the following:

1. Client A enters function 1: It disconnects all existing connections to `AmqpClient::resourceLocked` and then connects itself to that signal.
2. Client B now also enters function 1: It also disconnects all existing connections to `AmpqClient::resourceLocked`, in particular the one just established by client A. It then connects itself to that signal.
3. The `AmpqClient` handles client A's `lockResource` request. It acquired the requested resource and emits the `resourceLocked` signal.
4. Client B, being the only one connected to the signal, now executes `do_stuff` even though it was the resource requested by client A that was acquired.
5. The `AmpqClient` handles client B's `lockResource` request. Again, it successfully acquires the resource and emits the `resourceLocked` signal.
6. Client B, still being connected to that signal, executes `do_stuff` again.

The sequence above shows that `do_stuff` of client A not being called isn't too bad considering client B going to work while its resource hasn't even been acquired yet.

To fix this, you have to ensure to only call `do_stuff` of the client whose `lockResource` request was just handled. A signal - which by design always notifies *all* observers - just is a suboptimal approach because the observers would then need to check if the signal was meant to notify them or someone else.

A first fix is to modify the `lockResource` signal to also send the `this` pointer of the client that emits the signal. That way `AmqpClient` can use that pointer to call the client back when it acquired the resource.

One implementation of the slot connected to the signal then might look like this:

```
void AmqpClient::handleLockResourceRequest(int identifier,
                                           QObject* requestingClient)
{
   // try to acquire resource described by `identifier`

   if (resource_acquired_successfully)
   {
       QMetaObject::invokeMethod(requestingClient, "do_stuff", Qt::AutoConnection);
   }
 }
```

Note that in order for `invokeMethod` to work, `do_stuff` has to be either a slot or needs to be marked as `Q_INVOKABLE`.

But I'd go one step further than just having `do_stuff` be called via `invokeMethod`: As far as I can tell, `AmqpClient` is the only listener connected to `lockResource`, and were the two objects in the same thread you probably would just use a direct call `amqp_->tryToLockResource(identifier)` instead of 
`emit lockResource(identifier)`. I.e. the only reason you use the signal is so that the call goes through the event loop.

Instead of using a signal you could also use `invokeMethod` to request acquisition of the resource through the event loop. That has the advantage that your client class is no longer exposing the fact that it needs to acquire resources to do its job to users of that class.

All in all, the resulting code would look something like this:

```
class ClientType : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  // ...

  Q_INVOKABLE void do_stuff(); // definition as before

private:
   void requestResource(); // was previously code block 1 in your question

private:
  AmqpClient* amqp_;
  // ...
};

inline void ClientType::requestResource() 
{
  auto identifier = ...; // create resource identifier

  QMetaObject::invokeMethod(amqp_, 
                            "requestResource", 
                            Qt::AutoConnection, 
                            Q_ARG(int, identifier),
                            Q_ARG(QObject*, this));
}



class AmqpClient : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  // ...

  Q_INVOKABLE requestResource(int identifier, QObject* requestingClient); 

};

inline void AmqpClient::requestResource(int identifier,
                                        QObject* requestingClient)
{
   // try to acquire resource described by `identifier`

   if (resource_acquired_successfully)
   {
       QMetaObject::invokeMethod(requestingClient, "do_stuff", Qt::AutoConnection);
   }
}
```

In the implementation above I've assumed that the resource identifiers are of type `int`, but of course you can use any other type registered with the Qt metatype system. Similarly, instead of passing `QObject`-pointers you could also use `ClientType*` (or an abstract base class to avoid introducing cyclic dependencies) after registering the pointer type with Qts metatype system.